# Build failed while running Katalon Studio from Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

Basically I am trying to follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqOKYDV7dj4&list=PLhW3qG5bs-L_D4ZePNNjvmIULuu6mBHbu&index=39

Here is the total configuration I followed.

1. I am currently using Jenkins on a Digital Ocean Linux server (CentOS 7.0).
2. Installed Katalon Studio plugins from Jenkins.
3. In Jenkins added the Git repository "https://github.com/Raghav-Pal/KatalonTestsDemo.git"
   [image]
4. In the Build section of Jenkins, I choose "Execute Katalon Studio Tests" and added the below

a. Download Katalon Studio version: 7.0.0

b. Command arguments: `"-retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/TestSuite1" -executionProfile="default" -browserType="Web Service""`

[image]

Now, When I tried to build this project I am getting an error in the console output of the Jenkins.

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Katalon_automation
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Raghav-Pal/KatalonTestsDemo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Raghav-Pal/KatalonTestsDemo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/Raghav-Pal/KatalonTestsDemo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 464472c71aa92f88c29a57a354e61529ff5fcb78 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 464472c71aa92f88c29a57a354e61529ff5fcb78 # timeout=10
Commit message: "added test3"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 464472c71aa92f88c29a57a354e61529ff5fcb78 # timeout=10
[2019-11-10T09:33:40.774794] Katalon Studio package has been downloaded already.
[2019-11-10T09:33:40.775052] Using Katalon Studio at /var/lib/jenkins/.katalon/7.0.0/Katalon_Studio_Engine_Linux_64-7.0.0
[2019-11-10T09:33:40.775144] Making driver executables...
[2019-11-10T09:33:40.775184] Drivers folder at: /var/lib/jenkins/.katalon/7.0.0/Katalon_Studio_Engine_Linux_64-7.0.0/configuration/resources/drivers
[2019-11-10T09:33:40.775698] Set chromedriver as executable !
[2019-11-10T09:33:40.775952] Set geckodriver as executable !
[2019-11-10T09:33:40.776834] Execute [sh, -c, /var/lib/jenkins/.katalon/7.0.0/Katalon_Studio_Engine_Linux_64-7.0.0/katalonc -noSplash  -runMode=console  -projectPath="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Katalon_automation"  -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/TestSuite1" -executionProfile="default" -browserType="Web Service" ] in /tmp/katalon-193415871343130816
[2019-11-10T09:33:44.570534] Katalonc: Cannot open display: 
[2019-11-10T09:33:44.570686] Katalonc:
[2019-11-10T09:33:44.570742] An error has occurred. See the log file
[2019-11-10T09:33:44.570766] /var/lib/jenkins/.katalon/7.0.0/Katalon_Studio_Engine_Linux_64-7.0.0/configuration/1573378421474.log.
Build step 'Execute Katalon Studio Tests' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The error is

```
Katalonc: Cannot open display: 
[2019-11-10T09:33:44.570686] Katalonc:
[2019-11-10T09:33:44.570742] An error has occurred. See the log file
[2019-11-10T09:33:44.570766] /var/lib/jenkins/.katalon/7.0.0/Katalon_Studio_Engine_Linux_64-7.0.0/configuration/1573378421474.log.
Build step 'Execute Katalon Studio Tests' marked build as failure
```

I am also providing the error log `1573378421474.log` from the directory

```
/var/lib/jenkins/.katalon/7.0.0/Katalon_Studio_Engine_Linux_64-7.0.0/configuration/
```

Error log from the file `1573378421474.log`

```
!SESSION 2019-11-10 09:33:41.257 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11.0.5
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -runMode=console -projectPath=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Katalon_automation -retry=0 -testSuitePath=Test Suites/TestSuite1 -executionProfile=default -browserType=Web Service
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault -runMode=console -projectPath=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Katalon_automation -retry=0 -testSuitePath=Test Suites/TestSuite1 -executionProfile=default -browserType=Web Service

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-11-10 09:33:44.136
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.kms.katalon.application (26).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.kms.katalon.application.KatalonApplicationActivator.start() of bundle com.kms.katalon.application.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:795)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.createLicenseFolder(Application.java:238)
        at com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.start(Application.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.events.EventBrokerFactory.compute(EventBrokerFactory.java:29)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ValueComputation.get(ValueComputation.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.internalGet(EclipseContext.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.get(EclipseContext.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.get(EclipseContext.java:589)
        at com.kms.katalon.application.KatalonApplicationActivator.start(KatalonApplicationActivator.java:32)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 45 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.events.EventBrokerFactory.compute(EventBrokerFactory.java:29)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ValueComputation.get(ValueComputation.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.internalGet(EclipseContext.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.get(EclipseContext.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.get(EclipseContext.java:589)
        at com.kms.katalon.application.KatalonApplicationActivator.start(KatalonApplicationActivator.java:32)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.createLicenseFolder(Application.java:238)
        at com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.start(Application.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 45 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-11-10 09:33:44.158
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/kms/katalon/application/utils/ApplicationInfo
        at com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.createLicenseFolder(Application.java:238)
        at com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.start(Application.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.kms.katalon.application (26).
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.kms.katalon.application.KatalonApplicationActivator.start() of bundle com.kms.katalon.application.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:795)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.events.EventBrokerFactory.compute(EventBrokerFactory.java:29)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ValueComputation.get(ValueComputation.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.internalGet(EclipseContext.java:250)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.get(EclipseContext.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.get(EclipseContext.java:589)
        at com.kms.katalon.application.KatalonApplicationActivator.start(KatalonApplicationActivator.java:32)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

Comment: do you use any profiles when you use Katalon ?(to Store Global Variables? )

Comment: @Iahimadhe, No I do not used any profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was

```
java.version=11.0.5
```

Using `java version "1.8.0_231"` now

Now katalon is launched in Linux CentOS.
Though, can not run the test from command-line as Jenkins build is marked failed

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Katalon_automation
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Raghav-Pal/KatalonTestsDemo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Raghav-Pal/KatalonTestsDemo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/Raghav-Pal/KatalonTestsDemo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 464472c71aa92f88c29a57a354e61529ff5fcb78 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 464472c71aa92f88c29a57a354e61529ff5fcb78 # timeout=10
Commit message: "added test3"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 464472c71aa92f88c29a57a354e61529ff5fcb78 # timeout=10
[2019-11-13T16:16:20.361] Katalon Studio package has been downloaded already.
[2019-11-13T16:16:20.361] Using Katalon Studio at /var/lib/jenkins/.katalon/7.0.0/Katalon_Studio_Engine_Linux_64-7.0.0
[2019-11-13T16:16:20.361] Making driver executables...
[2019-11-13T16:16:20.361] Drivers folder at: /var/lib/jenkins/.katalon/7.0.0/Katalon_Studio_Engine_Linux_64-7.0.0/configuration/resources/drivers
[2019-11-13T16:16:20.362] Set chromedriver as executable !
[2019-11-13T16:16:20.363] Set geckodriver as executable !
[2019-11-13T16:16:20.364] Execute [sh, -c, /var/lib/jenkins/.katalon/7.0.0/Katalon_Studio_Engine_Linux_64-7.0.0/katalonc -noSplash  -runMode=console  -projectPath="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Katalon_automation"  -retry=0 -testSuitePath="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Katalon_automation/Test\ Suites/TestSuite1" -executionProfile="default" -browserType="Web Service" ] in /tmp/katalon-1472224603496043268
[2019-11-13T16:16:23.723] Katalon workspace folder is set to default location: /var/lib/jenkins/.katalon/7.0.0/Katalon_Studio_Engine_Linux_64-7.0.0/config
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.061] Starting Groovy-Eclipse compiler resolver.  Specified compiler level: unspecified
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.065] 171 2.4.7.xx-201611170128-e46 = ACTIVE
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.455] 
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.455] 
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.458] INFO: Katalon Version: 7.0.0
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.461] INFO: Command-line arguments: -runMode=console -projectPath=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Katalon_automation -retry=0 -testSuitePath=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Katalon_automation/Test\ Suites/TestSuite1 -executionProfile=default -browserType=Web Service
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.467] INFO: User working dir: /tmp/katalon-1472224603496043268
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.469] INFO: TestOps server URL: https://analytics.katalon.com
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.472] INFO: Katalon Store server URL: https://store.katalon.com
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.473] INFO: User home: /var/lib/jenkins
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.474] INFO: Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.476] INFO: Java version: 1.8.0_231
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.476] INFO: Local OS: Linux 64bit
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.611] INFO: CPU load: 0%
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.620] INFO: Total memory: 15884 MB
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.621] INFO: Free memory: 4689 MB
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.650] INFO: Machine ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.650] 
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.650] 
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.653] Activating...
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.658] Start activating offline...
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.658] Finding valid offline licenses in folder: /var/lib/jenkins/.katalon/license
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.916] The number of valid offline licenses: 0
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.916] The number of Runtime Engine running sessions: 2
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.916] License quota exceeded
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.917] Offline activation failed.
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.917] Start activating online...
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.926] Online activation for console mode failed.
[2019-11-13T16:16:24.926] Activation failed. Please make sure you are using a valid license.
Build step 'Execute Katalon Studio Tests' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So ultimately I need to purchase license for running Katalon test from command line.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be the browser setting. In the Katalon Documentation, the -browserType command line option specifically says, "Only Chrome, Firefox and Remote is available for use in Linux version." but you are trying to call "Web Service".

https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/console-mode-execution.html#general-options

Comment: That is not the issue. I am trying to execute an API test suite that's why -'browserType=Web Service' is used.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Katalon version 7.0 you need a license to execute from command line.
Use a lower version and try it out. But you have to be careful as some imports and methods are not supported on lower versions as lower versions are deprecated and no further support available.